# Update xaml control bound with viewmodel property from background thread or on timer tick

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I have view model which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public ref class MyViewModel sealed: Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public:
    // Inherited via INotifyPropertyChanged
    virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;

    property float Temperature
    {
        float get() { return m_temperature; }
        void set(float temperature) { SetProperty(m_temperature, temperature, "Temperature"); }
    }

    protected:
        void OnPropertyChanged(Platform::String ^ propertyName);

    private:
        float m_temperature = 0.0f;

    protected private:
        template<typename T>
        bool SetProperty(T& storage, T value, Platform::String^ propertyName)
        {
            if (storage == value) return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
}
```

In the MainPage timer tick I am trying to update the related control as below :

```
void MainPage::OnDeviceControllerPollingTick(Object^ sender, Object^ e)
{
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
    ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]()
{
    const float temperature = 10.0f;
    MyViewModelObject->Temperature = temperature;
}));
}
```

Is the proper way to update bound control from timer tick or background thread?

Comment: You could not update your UI without main thread, it is by design, for detail steps please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive).